# Understanding Fluent NHibernate reflexive relationship with null value

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

Suppose we have the following entity:

```
public class cuenta
{        
    public virtual double id { get; set; }
    public virtual string nombre_cuenta { get; set; }
    public virtual cuenta sumariza_en { get; set; }
}
```

When creating an account you can summarize this in an existing account, as I keep my entity to allow null values​​?
Currently I get the following error:
`Invalid Cast (check your mapping for property type mismatches)`

It is possible to do something like `public virtual cuenta? sumariza_en { get; set; }`

Comment: I could solve this problem again regenerating my model, not really that was failing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could solve this problem again regenerating my model, not really that was failing